# Extending Modules in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, module

I have a folder within my `lib` folder that holds a module and some submodules. Simplified it looks like this:

Folder structure

```
lib/bottles  
lib/bottles/bottles.rb  
lib/bottles/caps.rb
```

bottles.rb

```
module Bottles
  def hello_bottles
    puts "Hello Bottles"
  end
end
```

caps.rb

```
module Bottles
  module Caps
    def hello_caps
      puts "Hello Caps"
    end
  end
end
```

Also, in `config/application.rb` I have the following line:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

I include the module and it's submodules in my class like so:

```
class MyClass
  extend Bottles
  extend Bottles::Caps
end
```

The problem is that calling `MyClass.hello_caps` works just fine and prints `"Hello Caps"`, but calling `MyClass.hello_bottles` gives me an undefined method error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'hello_bottles' for MyClass
```

What is the correct syntax and configuration for extending the top level `Bottles` module so I can use its methods as class methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way Rails auto loads things I believe. Because it will look for the top level module in a file located in `<load_path>/bottles.rb` it is not finding it (this is why caps works, because it looks for all submodules inside the directory with the same name as the top level module). So the solution is to move the bottles.rb file up a directory level.

Comment: This works, thanks. Feels a bit ugly though as not everything is grouped together anymore. Do you know of a way to make it work with both `bottles.rb` and `caps.rb` in the same folder?

Comment: My only suggestion would be to stop using the autloader and require explicitly where needed. Since lib is already on the load path you can just do `require "bottles/bottles"` and `require "bottles/caps"`

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that :)

Answer (score 1):

Rails expect different files structures, something like that:

```
lib/bottles.rb  
lib/bottles/caps.rb
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-algorithms-relative-references